# Как сменить кодировку или заменить символ замены в функции file_get_contents

Tags: php

Пытаюсь прочитать файл в котором написано:

> "Коровы летают!

C помощью функции **file_get_contents** но в ответ получаю:

> ������ ������!

Если надо то вот строка из кода:

```
file_get_contents(getcwd().'/fackts/1.txt');
```

Как это исправить и вернуть человечиский язык?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте изменить кодировку

```
$string = file_get_contents($path);
$string = iconv('CP1251', 'UTF-8', $string);
```

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите кодировку, выполнив этот код

```
echo mb_detect_encoding(file_get_contents(getcwd().'/fackts/1.txt'));
```

Если кодировка правильная(UTF-8), то, возможно, вы используете не те функции. Для кириллических строк нужно использовать функции для работы с многобайтовыми строками (см. http://php.net/manual/ru/ref.mbstring.php)

Либо же на всем сервере настроена не та кодировка.